# Resgatar valor do banco de dados com React JS

Tags: javascript, html, react

Estou tentando resgatar uma informação do banco de dados mas não consigo transferi-la para texto. Estou usando fetch para buscar, no console.log a informação aparece, mas no html não.

```
import "./styles.css";
import "../../../css/csstables.css"
import NavBar from '../../../components/NavBar';
import SideBar from '../../../components/SideBar';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const UsersEdit = () => {

    const {id} = useParams();
    const [userResgatado, setUserResgatado] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/${id}`,{
            method: 'GET', 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'aplication/json',
            },
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            setUserResgatado(data)
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch (err => console.log(err))
    }, [id])

    return (
        <>
        <NavBar />
            <div className='divleft'>
                <SideBar />
            </div>
            <div className='divright'>

            <h2>Teste {userResgatado.usuario_email} </h2><br />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default UsersEdit;
```

O problema é ali no userResgatado, que não estou conseguindo puxar a informação. Mas no console aparece, segundo imagem anexada. Desde já, obrigado.

[image: erro]

Answer (score -3):

Creio que o problema é que você está salvando os dados dentro de um Array e depois o chamando como se fosse um objeto.

Ao fazer o `console.log` de data, note que ele mostra um *Array* com *length* == 1.

Dessa forma, você pode melhorar a maneira que armazena `userResgatado` ou, simplesmente colocá-lo na tela usando `userResgatado[0].usuario_email`.

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Boas respostas são descritivas, detalhadas e diretas. Ofereça o máximo de informações possíveis sobre a solução, aqui os usuários não podem (nem querem) ficar conversando. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).